# Remove rows from dataset using query

Tags: dataset, query

`MyDataSet[Select[#point[Fsr] == 1 &]]` returns the row I want to delete, now I am trying what looks to me the most logic command to remove these rows, which is 
`MyDataSet[Delete[#point[Fsr] == 1 &]]`
`MyDataSet[DeleteCases[#point[Fsr] == 1 &]]`, but neither works .... any idea how this should be done?

Comment: What does `MyDataSet[Select[#point[Fsr] != 1 &]]` do?

Comment: ... undeniably it gives me a new dataset without the rows I wanted to remove, but I have two concerns about this method: 1) for a large dataset, isn't it better to pullout what you do not need (a few items) rather than recreating a large dataset? 2) I wonder if there are cases where reversing the condition in `Select` does not do the job...

Comment: Well, an expression test is an expression test, negated or not. It will have to go through each row to return its results.

Comment: I do not have a large thing to test this on, but sounds like one of these Mathematica performance things, like Table performs very differently from Map ...

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way, not necessarily the most efficient:

`MyDataSet[Select[#point[Fsr] == 1 & /* Not]]`

Comment: That's just composing `Not[]` and the equality test, no? Why not use `Unequal[]` to begin with?

Comment: @J.M., correct, the advantange of this composition over `Unequal` is it turns `Select` into delete independent of the matching logic, eg if the user replaced `==` by `<`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround if you use the *named row* style of `Dataset` (an association of associations) but don't actually apply `Dataset` to it.  You can still perform querying as you can with a dataset but will have to explicitly use `Query` instead of it being implicitly used in the *`dataset[...]`* format.

```
assco = Association @@ 
 MapIndexed[First@#2 -> #1 &]@
   {<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> -1|>};
```

Here I have just indexed them with row number but you can use any expression. Now `KeyDropFrom` can be used with `Select` to drop the rows you are not interested in without making a new copy of the data.  Below the rows with `"a"-> 5` are dropped; the first and last row.

```
KeyDropFrom[assco, Keys@Select[#a == 5 &][assco]];
assco
(* <|2 -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>|> *)
```

The second row remains  in `assco` with the others dropped.

Hope this helps.